# How to add listView item base on date range?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xaml, listview

i doing wpf some generating columns base on date range. how could  i manage to get data count base on my sqlite data(shiftdate) and dynamically adding items to a List View?

I want something like this:
[image]

My Sqlite Data using sqlite viewer:
[image]

so far my code work only in the first column;

In my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SaranacHUD.AdminFeedback"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SaranacHUD"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
    Title="Feedback" Height="800" Width="1200" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Topmost="True">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <ListView Name="listView1" Margin="10,42,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionAccount}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gridViewAll">
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <DatePicker Name="DatePicker1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106"/>
    <DatePicker Name="DatePicker2" Height="27" Margin="151,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="113"/>
    <Button Name="buttonGenerate" Content="Generate" Height="30" Margin="269,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="156"/>
    <Label Content="TO" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30"/>
</Grid>
```

Behind Code:

```
 public partial class AdminFeedback : Window
{
    ViewModel _ViewModel = null;

    string year1;
    string month1;
    string day1;

    string year2;
    string month2;
    string day2;

    public AdminFeedback()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _ViewModel = Resources["ViewModel"] as ViewModel;


        Loaded += (Ev, ev) =>
        {
            DatePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
            DatePicker2.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
        };

        DatePicker1.SelectedDateChanged += (Ev, ev) =>
        {
            year1 = DatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy");
            month1 = DatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MM");
            day1 = DatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd");
        };

        DatePicker2.SelectedDateChanged += (Ev, ev) =>
        {
            year2 = DatePicker2.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy");
            month2 = DatePicker2.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MM");
            day2 = DatePicker2.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd");
        };

        buttonGenerate.Click += (Ev, ev) =>
        {
            CreateColumns();
        };
    }

    private void CreateColumns()
    {
        gridViewAll.Columns.Clear();
        GridViewColumn UserName = new GridViewColumn();
        UserName.Header = "UserName";
        UserName.Width = 150;
        UserName.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("UserName");
        gridViewAll.Columns.Add(UserName);



        var startDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(year1), int.Parse(month1), int.Parse(day1));
        var endDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(year2), int.Parse(month2), int.Parse(day2));

        var tmp = startDate;
        while (tmp <= endDate)
        {
            GridViewColumn _gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            _gridViewColumn.Header = tmp.ToString("MM/dd");
            _gridViewColumn.Width = 50;
            _gridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("GridViewColumn");
            gridViewAll.Columns.Add(_gridViewColumn);
            tmp = tmp.AddDays(1);
        }

        _ViewModel.FillFeedback();

    }
}
```

In my ViewModel

```
public void FillFeedback()
    {
        sqliteConMain.connection.Close();
        sqliteConMain.connection.Open();

        var _command = sqliteConMain.connection.CreateCommand();
        var query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tblUser Where Site = '" + "1880" + "' COLLATE NOCASE");
        string commandText = query;

        var _dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(commandText, sqliteConMain.connection);

        DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable _dataTable = new DataTable();

        _dataSet.Reset();
        _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet);

        sqliteConMain.connection.Close();

        _dataTable = _dataSet.Tables[0];
        var rows = _dataTable.Rows;

        CollectionAccount.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            var userName = row.ItemArray[0] as string;
            string teamNumber = row.ItemArray[1] as string;
            string groupName = row.ItemArray[2] as string;
            string site = row.ItemArray[3] as string;
            string switchRole = row.ItemArray[4] as string;

            var UserDataProperties = new UserDataProperties
            {
                UserName = userName,
                TeamNumber = teamNumber,
                GroupName = groupName,

            };

            _collectionAccount.Add(UserDataProperties);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at this: [ListView DataBinding](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/)

As is described near the end of the page, you will need to create an item template to display the information from the collectionAccout properly. How else is the view going to know how to render UserDataProperties?

Try something like this:

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <WrapPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="UserDataProperties: " />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Teamnumber}" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />

           </WrapPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Of course it will need some tweaking until it looks exactly like you want it to.